# jQuery POST not executing php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following jQuery in my index.php file (www root):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            $.post("php/login.php",
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                
            function(data,status){
                $("#loginstatus").html(data);
                alert(data);
        }
                   
        );
            
        });
    });
```

and the following php script in the folder php:

```html
<?php
    $username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : '' ;
    $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : '' ;
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "s150314";
    $dbpass = "password";
    $dbname = "users";
    $loginerror = "";
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    
    $sqlu = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username' ";
    $sqlp = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password LIKE '$password' ";
    $sqlfn = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username' ";
    
    $resultu = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlu) ;
    $resultp = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlp) ;
    $resultfn = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlfn) ;
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultu) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($resultu) > 0 ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultfn)) {
            $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $row["FirstName"];
        }
        echo "Success!";
        header("Location: ../pages/redirect.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }
    
?>
```

However there is no change on the submission of the form. In theory I am supposed to be redirected to redirect.php... if I replace the php code back into index.php it works flawlessly.

Comment: Sidenote: You can select everything in __ONE__ query

Comment: As you use `ajax` your redirect will not work as you expect. Refer to some web-basics.

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit

Comment: HI @Usaamah : Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @Usaamah : You didn't respond to the answer given below or to the question asked in comment section?

Answer (score 1):

Use [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

```
<script>
$.post("php/login.php",
{
    username: username,
    password: password
},
cache:false,
success:function(data){     
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        window.location.href="http:\\www.site_name.php/pages/redirect.php"";
    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        alert(data);
    }
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
$SqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName,LastName,username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND password LIKE '$password'";

$resultu = mysqli_query($conn, $SqlQuery) ;

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultu) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($resultu) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SqlQuery)) {
        $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $row["FirstName"];
    }
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
} else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
}
?>
```